# Maven returns an exit status of 0 even for failed builds?

Tags: linux, maven-2, exitstatus

I am using Maven v2.2.1 on my linux box. I have a build script that invokes mvn and does something based on the build status. I noticed that the exit status code is set to 0 irrespective of whether the mvn build fails or succeeds.

I also came across http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3651 which claims that the issue is fixed in v2.1.0-M1. Has anyone else noticed this?

Thx!

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375133/how-to-detect-a-build-error-from-ant-maven-via-a-bash-script

Comment: I'm wondering if Maven is distinguishing between a build error and a build failure.  A build error would be a problem with environment, or defect in Maven itself.  A build failure would be something like a compilation issue, where Maven didn't error out, it just was able to perform compilation.

Comment: facing similar issues with maven 2.0.9
if you resolved the issue, please post the solution.

Comment: maven 3.1.1 seems to work if that helps

Comment: I'm using maven 3.2.3 and have the same issue. Trying to deploy to a Nexus, getting SSL related errors but mvn insists in exiting with 0. How retarded.

Comment: shame on the mods closing this question. It's perfectly legitimate even if the OP forgot to put one obvious line in it.

Comment: On Maven 3.3.9 it still gives me `0`

Comment: cause in my case: piping the output of `mvn` to `grcat`