# Bat script exits unexpectedly

Tags: maven, batch-file

I have the following bat script:

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32
set JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre
set Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%Path%

cd C:\project
mvn validate compile package db-migration:migrate -DskipTests
REM script exits here, the second line never been executed
java  -jar target/compiled_tar.jar
```

The last line never been executed. The "mvn..." is successfully done, the compiled_tar.jar is created, the output is:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

If I insert the PAUSE command between last and previous lines the PAUSE also never been occurred. Why?

Comment: mvn might be quitting the entire process. I've had the same problem with some ant directives in the past, hope to see a solution as well.

Comment: Could do `mvn … && true` I think cmd may not have a true command see have to replace with `echo.` (almost the same, but prints a blank line). The trouble with this is you don't know if there was an error. What are the error codes for mvn?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1385644/537980

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Why does only the first line of this Windows batch file execute but all three lines execute in a command shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036754/why-does-only-the-first-line-of-this-windows-batch-file-execute-but-all-three-li)* - it is even the same BAT file, "mvn".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mvn` is itself a `.bat` file, so (for compatibility with MS-DOS 1.0) Windows will stop executing your batch file. To fix this, use the `call` command:

```
call mvn validate compile package db-migration:migrate -DskipTests
```

Comment: You have changed my life. Thanks!

Comment: The year is 2013 and I have to care about how MS-DOS 1.0 functioned 32 years ago. I don't know whether I should be sad or impressed.

Comment: @ChrisNielsen 2019 now.

Answer (score 0):

Using this Maven command (set maven_batch_pause=on) will solve this perfectly:

```
@echo off

set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32
set JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre
set Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%Path%

set maven_batch_pause=on
cd C:\project
mvn validate compile package db-migration:migrate -DskipTests

REM The script exits here, and the second line will never be executed
java  -jar target/compiled_tar.jar
```