# mvn in bash script if statement

Tags: bash, maven

I want to run the command mvn clean in a bash script. But I want to put it in an if statement. If the clean does not run properly I would like to exit out of the bash script with an echo statement.
Here is the code that is causing the problem:
    if [ mvn clean ]; then

I tried putting $(mvn clean) inside the if statement but there were too many arguments says the terminal. Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's what you want:

```
mvn clean
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Maven Clean Unsuccessful!"
    exit 1
fi
```

**Explanation:**

- `$?` is a [special shell variable](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/scrpt/scrpt2.2.2.html) that contains the exit code (whether it terminated successfully, or not) of the most immediate recently executed command.
- `-ne` is an option to the `test` [builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) `[`. It stands for "not equal". So here we are testing if the exit code from `mvn clean` is not equal to zero.
- `echo "Maven Clean Unsucccessful!"` - If this is the case, then we output some indicative message, and exit the script itself with an errant exit code.

When you do `$(mvn clean)`, that instead spawns a new subshell to run `mvn clean`, then simply dumps everything that was output to `stdout` in that subshell from running `mvn clean` to where `$(...)` was used in the parent shell.

---

**Alternatively**, you can do:

```
mvn clean || { echo "Maven Clean Unsuccessful"; exit 1; }
```

Which is just shorthand syntactic sugar for doing the same thing.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about your last method: `mvn clean || echo "Maven Clean Unsucccessful!" && exit 1`. I try to avoid as much as possible chains of `||`'s and `&&`'s. In your case, if `echo` fails, then `exit 1` will never be executed. When can this happen? oh nearly never I agree, but it could. E.g., after closing stdout as with `exec 1>&-`. Anyway, the proper answer to the question is the one given by choroba.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf the shorthand I wrote before was actually wrong, haha =p Looks like my edit went in a few seconds before your comment landed - see updated answer.

Comment: You must be joking! `mvn clean || {echo "Maven Clean Unsucccessful!"; exit 1}` is full of mistakes! Use single quotes for `echo 'Maven Clean Unsuccesssful!'` or escape the `!` (and remove the triple `s`); also, `{echo` is not a command (you must leave a space between `{` and the command), and you must put a semicolon at the last statement before the closing `}`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: thanks =) first time actually using `{...}`, didn't realize the subtleties.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Having to escape `!` in double-quotes is new to me too.

Answer (score 7):

No parentheses needed for checking the exit status:

```
if mvn clean ; then
   echo ok
else
   echo Something went wrong.
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a variable to capture the return code. Improves readability and allows running additional commands without fear of clobbering return code value:

```
mvn clean

MVN_RTN=$?
if [ "${MVN_RTN}" -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "Maven returned failure code ${MVN_RTN}"
   exit 1
fi
```