# Maven Returning 0 Even on Success in Cygwin

Tags: maven, cygwin

We use Apache maven for building our java code.  We use a Windows Desktop, but I'm running it under Cygwin (I use Cygwin as my main command line - and we have some scripting to make life easier which is done in Bash since then they work in our Linux environments too).

**Anyway, the `mvn` command (the Linux shell script variant) seems to always return `0` whether it succeeds or not under Cygwin!**  The file itself contains code designed to support Cygwin, so I assume it should work.

I spotted it first when it couldn't clean (as the app was running) but easiest way to reproduce is just to run a mvn command in a folder that doesn't contain a .pom file

On Cygwin:

```
$ mvn clean compile; RC=$?; echo "Exit value: $RC"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.145 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-12T13:30:20+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\cygwin64\home\foo.bar). Please verify you invoked Maven from
the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
Exit value: 0
```

If I run the same command on a CentOS machine it works as expected:

```
[adam@dev-adco-carc ~]$ mvn clean compile; RC=$?; echo "Exit value: $RC"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.641 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-06T02:52:18+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/foo). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
Exit value: 1
```

If I run the mvn.cmd (windows cmd file, not the linux sh file) then the return value works but the output is not good

```
$ mvn.cmd clean compile; RC=$?; echo "Exit value: $RC"
[←[1;34mINFO←[m] Scanning for projects...
[←[1;34mINFO←[m] ←[1m------------------------------------------------------------------------←[m
[←[1;34mINFO←[m] ←[1;31mBUILD FAILURE←[m
[←[1;34mINFO←[m] ←[1m------------------------------------------------------------------------←[m
[←[1;34mINFO←[m] Total time:  0.156 s
[←[1;34mINFO←[m] Finished at: 2021-07-12T18:20:43+03:00
[←[1;34mINFO←[m] ←[1m------------------------------------------------------------------------←[m
[←[1;31mERROR←[m] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\cygwin64\home\foo.bar). Please verify you invoked M
aven from the correct directory. -> ←[1m[Help 1]←[m
[←[1;31mERROR←[m]
[←[1;31mERROR←[m] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the ←[1m-e←[m switch.
[←[1;31mERROR←[m] Re-run Maven using the ←[1m-X←[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[←[1;31mERROR←[m]
[←[1;31mERROR←[m] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[←[1;31mERROR←[m] ←[1m[Help 1]←[m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
Exit value: 1
```

Using Apache Maven version 3.6.3 on both Windows and Linux

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375133/how-to-detect-a-build-error-from-ant-maven-via-a-bash-script) but it just explains how to test the return code - and in my case the return code is wrong.  It refers to a bug fixed in 2.0.9 with the mvn.cmd but it seems Cygwin does something similar to this in 3.6.3.

**Is anyone running in Cygwin and testing for success?  Am I missing something obvious or have I found a bug?**

Comment: Just a thought: You might try the Windows subsystem for Linux.